# MySQL query optimisation for sorting items by date & state

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, prestashop

I'm facing a mySQL problem : 
I got a mySQL table wich contains these columns, it's store every orders and every state of the orders :

```
    id_order_history / id_employee / id_order / id_order_state / date_add
```

I would like to get a list of *id_order* which are in a specific *id_order_state* - let's say 10 - but i don't want to get the orders where the state change after this particular state and don't want to collect the orders which are less than 7 day old ...

Here is how i tought to do this :

First a query to get a list of orders & date :

```
SELECT id_order, date
           FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'ps_order_history, 
           WHERE TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(date_add) <= 7 
           AND id_order_state = 10
```

then a loop to get only the orders without newest state :

```
$query = '   SELECT id_order, date
           FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'ps_order_history, 
           WHERE ';

foreach ( $listAbove, $item) {
     $query =+ '
                (( date > $item['date'])
                AND ( id_order = $item['id']))
             ';
 }
 $orderlist = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($query);
```

It's not really optimise, i pretty sure i can do it with only one query but don't really know how.

Do you have a clue to how make this cleaner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right, you only want the orders where the **most recent state** is equal to 10, for example. So lets start by getting the orders and the most recent state

```
SELECT
   id_order,
   MAX(id_order_history) as m
FROM ps_order_history
GROUP BY id_order
```

That gives us the latest order history item for each order (assuming `id_order_history` is the PK and that the largest value indicates the most recent order entry). Now we just search on that subquery to find the criteria we want.

```
SELECT
   poh.id_order
FROM ps_order_history poh
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT
   id_order,
   MAX(id_order_history) as m
 FROM ps_order_history
 GROUP BY id_order) sub
 ON sub.id_order = poh.id_order
   AND sub.m = poh.id_order_history
WHERE poh.id_order_state = 10
   AND TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(poh.date_add) <= 7
```

Comment: This solution looks good, the only thing I would change is to recommend to the OP to change the second part of the where clause to be `AND poh.date_add <= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`  That would allow use of an index on the `date_add` field whereas the current approach would not.

Comment: @MikeBrant That's a good suggestion, that part definitely needs work. I think a simple date subtraction might not get exactly what he wants done though, you could have something that was posted 7.1 days ago that is still technically within 7 days when you run `TO_DAYS`. But you are certainly right about the use of an index there

Comment: If the end desire is to show `date_add` values based on the an actual specific calendar day (starting at midnight), my proposed solution would be just fine, as you basically are calculating 00:00:00 of the current day (because of `DATE(NOW())`) and using that as the comparison with `date_add`. To me this is much cleaner from a logic standpoint.

Comment: Hello @mattedgod and thank you for your answer. Sorry for my english, there is a misunderstanding : the value of the state don't really tell us if it's most recent or not. The state can be at 10 today and at 2 tomorrow... I really have to sort the id by date.
The date format is 2009-04-07 09:58:02 btw

Comment: Here is the final request : 
`SELECT a.id_order
            FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_history a
            INNER JOIN 
                (SELECT id_order, MAX(date_add) as m
                FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_history
                GROUP BY id_order) sub
                ON sub.id_order = a.id_order
                    AND sub.m = a.date_add
                WHERE a.id_order_state = 18
                    AND TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(a.date_add) > 7`

Thx for your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query in the `WHERE` clause. Here's an example:

```
create table order_history 
(orderid int, orderstate int, orderdate date, 
primary key(orderid, orderstate, orderdate));

insert into order_history values (1,1,makedate(2012,1));
insert into order_history values (1,2,makedate(2012,2));
insert into order_history values (1,3,makedate(2012,3));
insert into order_history values (2,1,makedate(2012,1));
insert into order_history values (2,3,makedate(2012,3));
insert into order_history values (3,1,makedate(2012,1));
```

This query will now select all items whose latest `orderstate` is 3:

```
select a.orderid, a.orderdate from order_history a
where a.orderdate = 
  (select max(orderdate) from order_history b where b.orderid = a.orderid)
and a.orderstate=3
```

To restrict by orderdate, just add another clause for your date selection to the outer `where` clause.